# C# How to count all comboboxes that have the same selected value?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a window form application in C# which has a lot of comboboxes. 
All of them have the same items. 
What I want to do is to count all the comboboxes that have same selected value and put it in a textbox. For example if I have 2 of the comboboxes have the selected value are item 1's value and 3 of the comboboxes have the selected value are item 2's  value then the result in the textbox1 will be 2 and in the textbox2 it is 3.
Thank you. 
Sorry if my English is bad :(

Comment: What if you have five combo boxes, two have the value 1, and three have the value 2?

Comment: I mean I had a lot of comboboxes which is divided into 4 items, now I want to count how many of them have the selected value are item 1's value and put it in textbox1 as result 1, and how many have the selected value are item 2's value and put in textbox2 as result 2,...

Comment: What part are you not sure about? How to enumerate the comboboxes, or how to keep track of which have the same numbers?

Comment: If you want to check all the `ComboBox` controls of a given parent control, you can use `foreach (Control c in parentControl.Controls) if (c is ComboBox) ...`. here, `parentControl` could be your form, a panel, or whatever is the container holding your `ComboBox` controls.

Comment: @lurker sorry if I don't explain it good enough for you to understand, I have 30 comboboxes divided into 4 items, now I have to count how many have the selected value are item 1's value and put it in text box 1, and count how many have the selected value are item 2's value and put it in text box 2,... At last, I need 4 textbox all have resutl in it.

Comment: The information I provided is probably one tool you'll need to use. If your 30 comboboxes are divided into 4 items, in what way are they divided? Are they contained in 4 parent controls? If not, they probably should be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the comboboxes in an enumerable like e.g. an array. Then loop over them using e.g. `foreach`. In each iteration check if the selected value is the one you search and increment a counter, if the value was found. Assign the value of the counter to your textbox.

Assuming you want to do it in a method of the form, all relevant controls are direct children of the form, your comboboxes in one column are `comboBox1`, `comboBox2` and `comboBox3`, the value you search for is `"A"` and the textbox you want to show the count is `textBox1`, something like this

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (ComboBox comboBox in new ComboBox[] { this.comboBox1, this.comboBox2, this.comboBox3 })
{
    if (comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "A")
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
this.textBox1.Text = counter.ToString();
```

is what you're searching for. Adapt where needed.

Comment: I tried with your code and replace all the name in my form but it said Object reference not set to an instance of an object. c#  Null ReferenceException